# What does Tensor[batch_mask, ...] do?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, bilstm

I saw this line of code in an implementation of BiLSTM:

```py
batch_output = batch_output[batch_mask, ...]
```

I assume this is some kind of "masking" operation, but found little information on Google about the meaning of `...`.  Please help:).

**Original Code:**

```py
class BiLSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, tagset, embedding_dim, hidden_dim,
                 num_layers, bidirectional, dropout, pretrained=None):
         # irrelevant code ..........

    def forward(self, batch_input, batch_input_lens, batch_mask):
        batch_size, padding_length = batch_input.size()
        batch_input = self.word_embeds(batch_input)  # size: #batch * padding_length * embedding_dim
        batch_input = rnn_utils.pack_padded_sequence(
            batch_input, batch_input_lens, batch_first=True)
        batch_output, self.hidden = self.lstm(batch_input, self.hidden)
        self.repackage_hidden(self.hidden)
        batch_output, _ = rnn_utils.pad_packed_sequence(batch_output, batch_first=True)
        batch_output = batch_output.contiguous().view(batch_size * padding_length, -1)
        
        #######  HERE  ##########
        batch_output = batch_output[batch_mask, ...]
        #########################

        out = self.hidden2tag(batch_output)
        return out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `batch_mask` is a boolean tensor. In that case, `batch_output[batch_mask]` performs a boolean indexing that selects the elements corresponding to `True` in `batch_mask`.

`...` is usually referred as *ellipsis*, and in the case of PyTorch (but also other NumPy-like libraries), it is a shorthand for avoiding repeating the column operator (`:`) multiple times. For example, given a `tensor` `v`, with `v.shape` equal to `(2, 3, 4)`, the expression `v[1, :, :]` can be rewritten as `v[1, ...]`.

I performed some tests and using either `batch_output[batch_mask, ...]` or `batch_output[batch_mask]` seems to work identically:

```py
t = torch.arange(24).reshape(2, 3, 4)

# mask.shape == (2, 3)
mask = torch.tensor([[False, True, True], [True, False, False]])

print(torch.all(t[mask] == t[mask, ...]))  # returns True
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement masks the first dimension of `batch_output` with the indices contained by `batch_mask`. In practice, this means you are selecting some of the elements from the batch.

Here is a practical example:

```
>>> x = torch.rand(3,1,4,4)
tensor([[[[0.5216, 0.1122, 0.0396, 0.5824],
          [0.7685, 0.5583, 0.2817, 0.9678],
          [0.8878, 0.9477, 0.2554, 0.8261],
          [0.2708, 0.3403, 0.7734, 0.2584]]],


        [[[0.5471, 0.5031, 0.3906, 0.7554],
          [0.1895, 0.3985, 0.7083, 0.7849],
          [0.3128, 0.6733, 0.9223, 0.5345],
          [0.2689, 0.9876, 0.1092, 0.7405]]],


        [[[0.9834, 0.0276, 0.7114, 0.2872],
          [0.3483, 0.2104, 0.1816, 0.5615],
          [0.4323, 0.5329, 0.9198, 0.8647],
          [0.9054, 0.5763, 0.7939, 0.8388]]]])
```

With a mask and masking operation:

```
>>> mask = [0, 2]
>>> x[mask]
tensor([[[[0.5216, 0.1122, 0.0396, 0.5824],
          [0.7685, 0.5583, 0.2817, 0.9678],
          [0.8878, 0.9477, 0.2554, 0.8261],
          [0.2708, 0.3403, 0.7734, 0.2584]]],


        [[[0.9834, 0.0276, 0.7114, 0.2872],
          [0.3483, 0.2104, 0.1816, 0.5615],
          [0.4323, 0.5329, 0.9198, 0.8647],
          [0.9054, 0.5763, 0.7939, 0.8388]]]])
```

Where only the element at index `0` and `2` remains.

*Note: `x[mask]` is identical to `x[mask, ...]`, where the ellipsis is not necessary since all dimensions positioned will get all their indices selected by default.*